# Multiple Facebook Apps backed by same Spring Boot application

Tags: spring-security, spring-social, spring-social-facebook, spring-oauth2

So I was following the below (classic) tutorial for spring boot with facebook:

https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-boot-oauth2/

Everything is working fine, however I can't find documentation to help me implement my specific use case. So here it goes:

1. I'll have two facebook apps: one for the **owner** and another for the **regular user**
2. These two facebook apps will ask for different permissions (ex: for **owner** app it'll ask for permission to post in the fanpage and for the **regular user** it'll only for basic user info)
3. There will be two real application being one **mobile** (iOS and Android) and another **browser based application** (that's not really relevant)
4. REST API will be secured based on roles, meaning that the **owner** will have the **OWNER** role and the **regular user** will have the **REGULAR_USER** role, so that, for example, the **regular user** won't be able to call the API to post on the fanpage
5. Both applications will make it possible to login with or without facebook, because I need an users table to store more information and so
6. Eventually **regular user** can login as **owner** if he/she downloads the **owner* app

So, to summarize, I need:

1. Two facebook apps to be backed by same spring boot application
2. The ability to authorize an user with **APP ID X** and assign **OWNER** role and the ability to authorize an user with **APP ID Y** and assign role **REGULAR_USER**
3. To be able to configure (in the YML) two different facebook apps
4. The user to be able to merge existing account with facebook if he authorizes later on

I guess that's it. I'll edit later if I find more useful information to provide.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[There is Dave Syer's](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/tree/master/tests/annotation/multi) project that shows how to set up an Authorization Server and multiple Resource Servers in the same app.

Similar question with solution: [OAuth2 SSO for multiple resource servers with spring boot and jHipster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28861189/oauth2-sso-for-multiple-resource-servers-with-spring-boot-and-jhipster/35881902#35881902)